# Why it takes much longer to install 18.04 LTS than 18.10?

Tags: 18.04, 18.10

I have reinstalled 18.10 on the same Thinkpad over 5 times. Each time took about 10 minutes. Installing 18.04lts on the same machine. Over 30 minutes have passed and it is still installing. About 40% done. How come? Is it installing more reliable combinaof programs?

Comment: You misunderstand 'stability' and 'reliability'. LTS software is NOT magically somehow more reliable or stable *to the user* (why would anyone want a less reliable system?) 'Stable' in this context merely means that *it won't change* - no new versions, no changed APIs, no changed keyboard shortcuts, no changed workflows.

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu 18.10 was officially release a few days ago. There's not as many updates to download when installing 18.10 as there are for 18.04. Your mileage may vary when installing Ubuntu depending on the mirror that is serving the updates.

Comment: Thanks. Is 18.04lts providing more stability? Never get brightness keys, black screen after 20-30 minutes of inactivity, hybrid GPU switching, wake from suspend working under 18.10.

Comment: 18.04 is the stablest Ubuntu version that I have ever used. Small nagging problems that bothered me in Ubuntu 16.04 disappeared when I updated it to 18.04.

Comment: Thanks. Still downloading. If still doesn’t work, will try other distributions.

Comment: Unfortunately same issues.